# Bootstrap hamburger menu dropdown not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Could someone explain to me why this isn't working?  When I click the hamburger menu nothing happens. I've tried including various bootstrap js and css files but nothing fixes it.

Here's my code.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blobula/xjy5eacp/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blog</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Did you change the class name of the Hamburger button? I can't see the Bootstrap toggle function since your JS is minified, but if it's looking for a specific class, changing anything would mess that up.

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery  at bootstrap.min.js:6`. It is preferred you check the console log ***before posting a question*** on [so].

Comment: When you include jQuery it works: https://jsfiddle.net/stvscvh4/

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add the jquery without which dropdown won't work.

**working fine**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           
           </head>
<body >
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blog</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was overlooking something simple.